# Manifold learning/nonlinear dimensionality reduction for beginners

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, manifolds, machine-learning

I'm a computer science graduate student.  I recently discovered manifold learning.  I think I understand the very basic, high-level concept of nonlinear dimensionality reduction, but I'd like a stronger background.  I majored in applied mathematics as an undergraduate, but did not take abstract algebra or topology.

Do I need to read up on algebra and topology to understand/effectively use manifold learning?  Regardless, does anyone have any references for a beginner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you take any differential geometry? That's primarily where you will find manifolds.

Comment: @fhyve No. I've pretty much have just taken (multiple *levels* of) calculus, linear algebra, diffeq, number theory, probability, statistics, optimization, and a bunch of CS-related math courses.  Nothing on analysis, abstract algebra, topology or differential geometry.

Comment: @fhyve any recommendations for someone with my background? ie, a good introductory text to differential geometry?  Will I be able to understand it without knowing topology? On that note, can I understand topology without knowing abstract algebra? I want to learn whatever I have to...

Comment: You can understand topology without algebra, since I don't think you will need any algebraic topology (though you would need that if you did topological data analysis which is super cool). Some topology will be helpful though I think you can get by without it. You will need a strong grasp of linear algebra, which might start getting into abstract algebra. I am not sure exactly what you will need for manifold learning, so I can't exactly recommend a text, but this might be helpful: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7834/undergraduate-differential-geometry-texts

Comment: @fhyve Okay, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, i think [Loring W. Tu](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441973990)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: You're welcome.